# How to return json with expressjs and catch it with axios?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

How can i get json answer from express with axios ?
example :

```
app.post("/page", (err, res) => {
  return res.json({message: "ok"})
}
```

and with axios

```
axios.post(addressApi, {param})
  .then(res => {
  console.log(SHOW JSON RESPONSE HERE);
  });
```

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find response data on `res.data`:

```
axios.post(addressApi, {param})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

(see [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) for more details)